# Get the values after # from url using php

Tags: php

i passing below url in address bar

www.example.com/latest_notes/?shareURL&adherentID=ascd#123
i want get the after # value of 123 this page 
i have tried SERVER function i  can able to get UL without #, Please any one help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieve the hash in the url with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957030/retrieve-the-hash-in-the-url-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the url string to a PHP url object with the function parse_url and dereference its "fragment" key like this:

```
$url=parse_url("www.example.com/latest_notes/?shareURL&adherentID=ascd#123");
echo $url["fragment"];
```

The above code returns 123

Comment: `$fragment = isset($url['fragment']) ? '#' . $url['fragment'] : '';` this would also be useful

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the function parse_url, it does what you need.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';
var_dump(parse_url($url));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
```

You need the #anchor values: use the last line of code

```
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
```

Possible duplicate question [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php?rq=1)